# Why does selecting all columns change the order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. The order of selecting with a `select *` is different than the order of selecting without the wildcard.

This issue is happening on a production environment.

[image]

I have tried to replicate this issue but have not succeeded.

What could be causing this issue in the production tables?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table2

CREATE TABLE #table1 (id int, code varchar(10), carriercode varchar(10), maxvalue numeric(14,3))
CREATE TABLE #table2 (id int, carriercode varchar(10))

-- notice the maximum value is always 2000.000
INSERT INTO #table1 (id,code,carriercode, maxvalue) SELECT 1,'a','carrier_a',2000.000
INSERT INTO #table1 (id,code,carriercode, maxvalue) SELECT 2,'a','carrier_b',2000.000
INSERT INTO #table1 (id,code,carriercode, maxvalue) SELECT 3,'c','carrier_c',2000.000
INSERT INTO #table2 (id,carriercode) SELECT 1,'carrier_a'
INSERT INTO #table2 (id,carriercode) SELECT 2,'carrier_b'
```

This is the select without the wildcard

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.code,t1.parentcode,t1.carriercode 
FROM #table1 t1
LEFT JOIN #table2 t2 on t1.carriercode=t2.carriercode
WHERE (t1.parentcode = 'a')
AND (t1.maxvalue >= 830 OR t1.maxvalue is null)
ORDER BY t1.maxvalue DESC
```

And the result

```
id  code    parentcode  carriercode
1   a1  a   carrier_a
2   a2  a   carrier_b
```

Here the select with the wildcard

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.code,t1.parentcode,t1.carriercode,* 
FROM #table1 t1
LEFT JOIN #table2 t2 on t1.carriercode=t2.carriercode
WHERE (t1.parentcode = 'a')
AND (t1.maxvalue >= 830 OR t1.maxvalue is null)
ORDER BY t1.maxvalue DESC
```

And the second result

```
id  code    parentcode  carriercode id  code    parentcode  carriercode maxvalue    dt  id  carriercode
1   a1  a   carrier_a   1   a1  a   carrier_a   2000.000    2022-09-30 22:49:52.787 1   carrier_a
2   a2  a   carrier_b   2   a2  a   carrier_b   2000.000    2022-09-30 22:49:52.787 2   carrier_b
```

Notice that the order of table 1 id column is the same for both select statements. On the production tables the 2 select statements are ordered differently.

What I have tried

1. Rounding issues: CAST numeric to int -> order is still the same for both selects
2. Changed the order of the initial inserts -> order is still equal for both selects

Comment: Your `maxvalue` values in both rows are the same (`2000.000`), so their relative ordering is undefined. **That's all there is to it**. The only way to be assured of any speciifc ordering is by _fully qualifying_ your `ORDER BY` clause (e.g. `ORDER BY t1.MaxValue, id`).

Comment: If the values of every row in the column you're ordering by are the same then SQL Server will return the results as it will, there's no guarantee across the other columns.  The production queries presumably have different execution plans so the data will get read differently.

Comment: "fully qualifying your order" thank you @Dai ... seems obvious now

Comment: In your 1st SQL statement, is it because the wildcard (i.e. *) would mean SQL server has to include all other columns for both T1 and T2 (which you did not show) into considerations when sorting anything outside the `MaxValue` field? Whereas in the 2nd SQL statement the 4 columns specified would mean it would not affect the order of `id` in relation to `MaxValue`. I hope you show also the values for `MaxValue` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the order of rows that are tied based on your ORDER BY is undocumented and depends on the details of the execution plan.

To fix the order, ensure your ORDER BY includes enough columns to uniquely order the rows.  EG

```
ORDER BY t1.maxvalue DESC, id
```